# Authentication with Google and my server backend

Tags: angular, security, google-authentication, ionic5, integrity

I am creating an application with ionic. I use google authentication, using the instructions on the web (https://www.pragma.com.co/academia/lecciones/como-implementar-un-login-de-google-con-ionic).
Everything works correctly and I obtain and validate the JWT as recommended by Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth).

My question is, after authenticating, I need to make get / post requests to my backend. What is the most efficient way to guarantee the authenticity of the petitions?
Send the JWT on each request and validate it? I think this is not very efficient and not secure.

Submit the access_token and validate it using https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token= <access_token>? Then it should control the relation acces_token <--> User and, how refresh this token?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial authentication and the jwt, you could create a plain old session with the standard session management feature of your server-side framework. This would be the most secure option, the client app would not hold the jwt at all, only a random session id, in a httpOnly cookie, secure against XSS. This implies you only have one origin (one backend domain your frontend app talks to).

You can send the jwt on each request and validate it every time, that's also fairly common, but jwts are not actually meant for that. You would likely hit your database anyway to check for revocation / logout so it would still not be stateless, the user would have more than a random number as the session token providing some attack surface, and if the jwt is not stored in a httpOnly cookie, it would also be susceptible to XSS.

If you stored the jwt in a httpOnly cookie, a plain old random session id is better and more secure in almost every case (with the notable exception of truly stateless applications, but that's a security tradeoff, and you don't actually need statelessness most of the time). One reason to actually use a jwt and not store it in a httpOnly cookie is if you want to send it to multiple origins, and then it's an architectural question if you want to have an API gateway or similar, or accept the risk of XSS (and mitigate it some other way).

Comment: In short, you should just create a plain old stateful session, based on the initial jwt you receive.  So 1. client goes to google idp and gets token 2. client sends jwt id token to your backend 3. backend creates and stores a random session id and sets it as a httponly cookie 4. subsequent requests are authenticated based on the session id. This session management is already part of whatever backend framework you use, you should not reimplement it. If all this is suitable for your usecase, it is likely the most secure option.